# Change pixel order of a .tiff file from rgbrgb to rrbbgg (interleaved to non-interleaved)

Tags: image-processing, tiff, interleave

I have been trying to figure out a way to create non-interleaved .tiff files, as described here: https://questionsomething.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/databending-using-audacity-effects/ (under the heading of "The photographic base").

It seems like it's a trivial thing using photoshop, but I'm on linux and would hate to get myself a copy just for this one option. If anyone knows of a way, be it via imagemagick, hacking the gimp or some obscure program, I'd be glad for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you really mean to change the order on pairs of pixels ?

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interlace

Comment: "would hate to get myself a copy": what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not exactly, I was trying to give the most information I had based on the description I had found. As Chris Luengo describes, I want the tif-file in planar configuration, not contiguous planar configuration. If I understand it all correctly, that is.

As for the copy I don't want to get myself: I don't want to buy and run photoshop just to change one aspect of an image.

Comment: It is possible to modify the file in-place, provided it fits in RAM twice. It is probably possible to do the reorganization by means of the Dutch flag algorithm directly on the file (provided the format is uncompressed), and this would be totally paranoid.

Comment: @fmw42 This works as well, thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If TIFF parlance, you have a file in contiguous planar configuration, and want separate planar configuration.

The `tiffcp` utility that comes with LibTIFF can do this for you. Use the `-p separate` option:

```sh
tiffcp -p separate src.tif dest.tif
```

See [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tiffcp).

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much!